# Unity Multiplayer FPS Client/Server Interaction Problems

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, multiplayer

I have a simple FPS where a player can fire a gun. I want the clients to see the bullet holes. I am trying to accomplish this by invoking a server side method when the client tries to fire the gun. The server side method should then raycast from the players camera and spawn a bullet hole for everyone to see..

I can get this to work partially by passing the player as a parameter to the server method. However, since my raycasting needs to be done based off the player camera, the bullet holes end up appearing at character height, since it's using the player and not the camera.

It won't allow me to pass a camera through. I have also tried creating an empty game object called bullet spawn and passing that through but I was getting a "object reference not set to instance of an object." This same error seems to surface for any Child element of the player I attempt to pass to the server side method.

I am unsure of the right way to accomplish this.

```
void Update()
{
    if (isLocalPlayer)
    {
        if (Input.GetButton("Fire1"))
        {
            CmdFire(BulletSpawn);
        }
    }
}

[Command]
void CmdFire(GameObject Player)
{
    Ray shooterRay = new Ray(Player.transform.position, Player.transform.forward);
    if (Physics.Raycast(shooterRay, out Hit, 10000))
    {
        Debug.Log("player hit");
        GameObject Bullet_Hole = (GameObject)Instantiate(BulletHole_Prefab, Hit.point, Quaternion.FromToRotation(Vector3.up, Hit.point));
        NetworkServer.Spawn(Bullet_Hole);
    }
}
```

Comment: This section should actually be this for example purposes... if (Input.GetButton("Fire1"))
                    {
                        CmdFire(Player);
                    }

Comment: Presumably you're syncing the position of the _gun_? It'd be easier for you to send the ray from the tip of the gun the player is using. The server has no instance representing the players camera of course so doing anything with a 'Camera' on the server wouldn't get you anywhere. You'd have to pass the camera view vector to the server some other way.

Comment: As of now I am just syncing the rotation and position of the player. Since the gun is a child object of the player, you see that's movement as well. Of course if you look up or down, that's not synced for the moment.  The problem with casting the ray from the tip of the gun is unless your gun is perfectly straight, your shot will not be centered in your screen. I am casting from the camera to ensure the bullet goes down the center. Typically for the gun to look like it is being held in game, it will be at an angle and slightly to right of your center screen which would make the shot feelweird.

Comment: I also just tried casting the ray locally and passing the ray to the server side method.It does work, however, there is some delay and it doesn't feel right. Still thinking....

Comment: I would fairly confidently say that every FPS fires bullets from the tip of the gun. Think about how broken it would appear in short range otherwise (e.g. somebody standing in front of a shooting gun doesn't get hit). The bullet hitting a target in the center of the screen would be entirely related to the angle of the gun.

Comment: FWIW, the simple and likely most common route (in fixed aim systems) is that a ray is fired from the camera (locally) to discover the point the player is targeting at. Then use your favourite `LookAt` method to make the gun point at it. Sync the gun's position. When the gun fires, the server fires a ray from the gun.

Comment: Think about it this way. What is it that you need to fire your weapon? You need the firing point and the firing direction (in your simple case). So try to pass just that information. Your CmdFire should look like `void CmdFire(Vector3 firingPoint, Vector3 firingDirection)`. Remember that when you pass the player gameobject, it gets serialized and sent to the server which causes a lot of unneeded network traffic. Stick to value types and simple objects for commands.

Answer (score 0):

> Think about it this way. What is it that you need to fire your weapon? You need the firing point and the firing direction (in your simple case). So try to pass just that information. Your CmdFire should look like void CmdFire(Vector3 firingPoint, Vector3 firingDirection). Remember that when you pass the player gameobject, it gets serialized and sent to the server which causes a lot of unneeded network traffic. Stick to value types and simple objects for commands.

This is what ultimately led me to the solution. Thank you for the advice. I simply passed two Vector3 parameters as you suggested which represent the raycast position and direction. I can now shoot from both client and server and see the bullet holes on both as well. Here is the code that fixed it in case anyone runs into this later on:

```
void Update() {
    if (isLocalPlayer) {
        if (Input.GetButton("Fire1")) {
            Vector3 FiringSpot = PlayerCam.transform.position;
            Vector3 FireDirection = PlayerCam.transform.forward;
            CmdFire(FiringSpot, FireDirection);
        }
    }
}

[Command]
void CmdFire(Vector3 firingPoint, Vector3 firingDirection) {
    Ray shooterRay = new Ray(firingPoint, firingDirection);
    if (Physics.Raycast(shooterRay, out Hit, 10000)) {
        GameObject Bullet_Hole = (GameObject)Instantiate(bullet_Hole_Prefab, Hit.point, Quaternion.FromToRotation(Vector3.up, Hit.point));
        NetworkServer.Spawn(Bullet_Hole);
        Destroy(Bullet_Hole, 10);
    }
}
```

Comment: FYI for anyone wanting to use this.... I just noticed there is a closing bracket missing for the Updated method. That's just a copy/paste error.